# Android - canvas drawing doubts

Tags: android, touch, draw, paint

I am looking at one of the sample applications from Google, which deals with touch drawing using canvas:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html

I have a few doubts:

1. I am not able to understand what's the role of Canvas versus the role
   of the bitmap.
2. In the `drawPoint` function, I am not able to
   understand this code snippet:

> ```
> mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, mPaint);
> mRect.set((int) (x - radius - 2), (int) (y - radius - 2),
>           (int) (x + radius + 2), (int) (y + radius + 2));
> invalidate(mRect);
> ```

If the circle is already drawn into the canvas above, then what happens in the `onDraw` function where the following code is given:

`canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Canvas vs Bitmap**

A `Bitmap` is what the name suggests: A normal image as a bitmap. The `Canvas` class is an editor for bitmaps. You use it to change the bitmap data, it holds all drawing methods. This principle behaves similar to the shared preferences *(if you already worked with them)*, you have a `SharedPreferences` class that holds the preferences, and an `Editor` class to change things.

**Drawing the circles**

This code does something similar to [double buffering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_buffering#Double_buffering). `drawPoint()` basically draws a circle into the `mBitmap` object¹. *But* this bitmap object is not yet visible. It exists in the memory. When `onDraw()` is called, it has a `Canvas` argument that represents the drawing surface of the view. All that `drawBitmap()` does here is use the prepared bitmap from the memory and draw it inside the views graphical representation to make it visible.

*¹ The used canvas `mCanvas` is tied to `mBitmap` inside `onSizeChanged()`*

Comment: In `drawPoint()`, the circle drawing call does not involve any bitmap at all! See: `mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, mPaint);` How does this work?

Comment: Yes thats what my ¹ point meant. When mBitmap is created with a certain size, mCanvas is assigned to it (line `            newCanvas.setBitmap(newBitmap);` , later on `mBitmap = newBitmap; mCanvas = newCanvas`). From this point on `mCanvas` edits the data inside `mBitmap`. And `mCanvas` is used here, it holds the drawing function `drawCircle()` as described in the first paragraph. That circle gets drawn inside the pixel data that the bitmap holds. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. From the Android SDK:

   > *The **[Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)** class holds the "draw" calls. To draw something, you need 4 basic components: A **[Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)** to hold the pixels, a Canvas to host the draw calls (writing into the bitmap), a drawing primitive (e.g. Rect, Path, text, Bitmap), and a paint (to describe the colors and styles for the drawing).*
2. I'm assuming you're referring to this snippet:

   ```
   @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
       if (mBitmap != null) {
           canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, null);
       }
   }
   ```

   Well it looks like an override of an inherited `onDraw` method which by default probably 'does nothing', hence the override to actually give it some behaviour, in this case given a non-null Bitmap instance, make the canvas draw it.

Answer (score 0):

if you go to the developper refference:

> drawBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, float left, float top, Paint paint)
>
> **Draw the
> specified bitmap, with its top/left corner at (x,y), using the
> specified paint,    transformed by the current matrix.**

Then if you see that mBitmap doesn't exist in the class , thats cause that var comes from the extend from another activity .

Canvas also has a setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) function . Then the solution is that that paint in canvas if you have set into it a bitmap object.